# Cleaning up debug commits in git

Tags: git, version-control

A lot of the time when I'm developing an app, I'll add logging statements, sometimes if it'll help debug, `die()` assertions, etc. Testing locally, I don't have to commit anything to git. When I want to get this over to a staging environment though with the commits in my feature branch, I'd have to commit them with a bunch of debug type code. Eventually, when I'm ready to merge the branch into a release branch, I'd love to have these numerous commits almost cleaned/compiled into one commit and it's as if the debug statements aren't there because I made one final commit to clean them up.

Is it possible to rewrite git history to merge all of these commits into one clean commit once I'm done working on my feature branch?

Answer (score 3):

As long as you haven't published your changes (`git push`) you can rewrite history safely with `git rebase`

You can `git rebase -i <commit>~1` where `commit` is the first commit from where you want to start cleaning up and in the interactive mode, you can `squash` the commit to somehow *merge* them into a big commit. You can find good documentation about this topic here: [7.6 Git Tools - Rewriting History](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History)

Also, [take a look into this](https://gist.github.com/pbu88/5a510b245bb81ac1fd64), is a small hook I did to prevent debug statements to be committed, maybe you find it useful.

*EDIT:* I see you mention that you need to move your changes to a *staging area*. If this implies pushing, then rewriting the history might be problematic unless no one else pull your changes. Rewriting the history changes your commits "sha", so other members of the team can end up with duplicated commits or with many conflicts.

On the other hand, if you push somewhere, but only you are using that *staging area*, then you can rewrite your history locally and push again with `git push -f`. It will update the branch with your local changes.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I find the following method most flexible:

1. Use `git reset commit-id` to unwind the commit history of your branch all the way back to the commit with ID `commit-id`, while preserving your file changes as uncommitted.
2. Optionally do some more changes (e.g. remove debugging code).
3. Re-commit changes into a clean set of commits. With a GUI tool like `git gui`, you can even select and commit individual lines out of a file.

Here is a detailed guide about the procedure:
https://github.com/jleben/code-review-prep-guide/blob/master/guide.md

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old and you probably solved it by now, just want to add my 2cents.

As I understand git and do it myself, the cleanest option seems to be to interactively rebase (as mentioned by @paulo bu, yet when you first merge your staging branch into your release branch, you can rebase without a problem as long as it hasn't been pushed.

Example, once everything has been commited:

```
staging$ git checkout release
release$ git merge staging
release$ git rebase -i
release$ git push
```

That's a little simplified of course but without any conflicts that can happen..

Before merging it might be interesting to get all upstream changes in if you have co-workers working on `release` as well..But that could happen afterwards as well..

In depth article on rebasing https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase